# Padding, list and background

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists, margin

Im really confused, it is strangest bug i have seen in my life.
Here is JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/c92mjkne/1/

As you can see, when our "comment" is hovered, `#content` get stange margins (but in CSS it have no margins). As i can know, it is `ol`'s margins. But why they are outside of parent div?
Ok, that's strange. BUT! When we changing `padding: 0;` to `padding: 1px;` in `#content`'s CSS, we see, that block have no margin! WTF? Help me please :D I really dont know how to google :D

Here is example:

```css
#head, #foot, #content {
    padding: 7px;`
}

#content {
    padding: 0;
}

#comment:hover div {
    background: #eee;
}

#comment {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#comment:hover {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
ul {
    margin: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="comment">
    <div id="head">
        Efog <span style="color: gray">today, 10:10 pm</span>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Stack</li>
            <li>Overflow</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="foot">
        <a href="?">answer</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is code with `padding: 1px`:

```css
#head, #foot, #content {
    padding: 7px;`
}

#content {
    padding: 1px;
}

#comment:hover div {
    background: #eee;
}

#comment {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

#comment:hover {
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
ul {
    margin: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div id="comment">
    <div id="head">
        Efog <span style="color: gray">today, 10:10 pm</span>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Stack</li>
            <li>Overflow</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="foot">
        <a href="?">answer</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for english, thanks.

Comment: Please don't accept Nathan's answer cause it doesn't explain why this is happening, I am also wondering what is going on with the padding and margin there.

Comment: I will not because it is solution of problem but not answer on my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As i can know, it is `ol`'s margins. But why they are outside of parent div?

Because they are *supposed* to be (the are not “outside” the `div`, they have become margins *of* the `div`) – http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins:

> “In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins that combine this way are said to *collapse*, and the resulting combined margin is called a *collapsed margin*.
>
> Adjoining vertical margins collapse, […]”

So no bug at all, but specs followed to the point.

> BUT! When we changing `padding: 0;` to `padding: 1px;` in `#content`'s CSS, we see, that block have no margin!

Read on at the above point,

> “Two margins are *adjoining* if and only if:
>   […]
>    - no line boxes, no clearance, no padding and no border separate them
>   […]”

Comment: Wow. Interesting. Ok then, how can i prevent collapsing?

Comment: By seeing to it that one of the “if and only if” conditions are _not_ met any more. In your example, for instance floating the `ul` (and give it 100% width at the same time, so that its width does not shrink-to-fit) could accomplish this, http://jsfiddle.net/c92mjkne/8/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/c92mjkne/2/

```
#comment:hover{
  background: gray;
}
```

It is normal, you set every div inside your comment div a background but you set some a margin. If you don't want any blank area, just set the background color to the div containing them all.

It's not a bug.

Comment: I don't think that is what he is asking. The weird thing about his example is that the margin disappears once you add ANY padding value to the `#content` div apart from 0.

Comment: Yeah, i did it at first, but i need to highlight only specific blocks in `#comment` when it is hovered. As example: http://jsfiddle.net/c92mjkne/4/